# R Mojave blurry quartz window

Tags: r, homebrew, core-graphics

For a long time, I've used the Homebrew version of R without any issues. However, since updating to Mojave, the text/lines displayed in quartz plot windows become blurry either when the plot window is resized or when plotting to a previously opened quartz window. In the absence of an open quartz window (`e.g., dev.off(...)`), the requested plot renders perfectly.

With respect to my Homebrew installation, the problem remains whether I install R using the bottled version or compile from source. There are no obvious build errors when looking at the config.log file. If I install the cask version of R, plots render properly with no issues. This suggests there must be a problem on my end. However, I never had any issues compiling R prior to Mojave.

It seems like an antialiasing issue but I have no idea how to track down the cause. I haven't observed any antialiasing issues anywhere else on my system.

I know this may seem like a vague/bad question given build environments can vary, but my research elsewhere has turned up nothing and this seems like a place to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

My Homebrew configuration and R sessionInfo is as follows:

```
#> brew --config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.8.6-14-ga2b4d4a
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: a2b4d4aac294ec0872cd84d44f65bd5bd507e166
Last commit: 2 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 0a1055eea4f707812a3103b349be6833fdde31f0
Core tap last commit: 2 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: --appdir=~/Applications
HOMEBREW_DEV_CMD_RUN: 1
HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: set
HOMEBREW_NO_ANALYTICS: 1
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE: 1
HOMEBREW_NO_EMOJI: 1
CPU: octa-core 64-bit ivybridge
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.7 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 10.0 build 1000
Git: 2.20.1 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 11.0.1, 11
macOS: 10.14.2-x86_64
CLT: 10.1.0.0.1.1539992718
Xcode: 10.1
CLT headers: 10.1.0.0.1.1539992718
XQuartz: 2.7.11 => /opt/X11`
```

```
#> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.2
Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.4/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.4.dylib
locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1
```

Comment: I have this problem as well, and have been unable to find any solution. I did notice that, with base R plots, the first plot on a new device is not blurry, but resizing the plot window or drawing additional plots makes the device blurry.